# Is it possible to post a message from my app directly to GooglePlus?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I have been playing around with the APIs and I found a good example of how to get Google Tasks back but I havn't found any examples showing how to post the Google+ wall.

Anyone know of any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this. At present, the Google+ API is read-only. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) (bolded for emphasis):

> Note: The Google+ API **currently provides read-only access** to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Comment: Follow the related issue here http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41

Comment: "... to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key." Does that mean its read only unless you use OAuth2.0?

Comment: No, it means [the entire API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/) requires OAuth or a key to use. The API's functions are still read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google+ history API](https://developers.google.com/+/history) to post moments to a user's private Google+ history. The user can approve your app/site for automatic posting to their stream.

**Note:** The Google+ History feature is still in [developer preview](https://developers.google.com/+/history/preview/), which means that you can start developing your app, testing your app, but **only** users that are registered with the developer preview, can use the feature. When the Google+ History feature leaves becomes generally available, you will be able to release your app to the public.